# Bottle GET request is broken with certain strings when running with paste server

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, wsgi, bottle

I have a problem similar to this one:
[Python bottle: UTF8 path string invalid when using app.mount()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168292/python-bottle-utf8-path-string-invalid-when-using-app-mount?rq=1)

When I try to GET `/languages/Inglês` I receive the error below (notice the accent "ê"). When passing [az] strings it works fine.

> Critical error while processing request: /languages/Inglês

I tried the fix mentioned on the link above without success.

**Working example**:

```
from bottle import route, run, debug

@route('/languages/<name>')
def hello(name):
    return name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    debug(False)
    #run(reloader=False, port = 8080) # works
    run(server='paste', port = 8080)  # fails
```

Running with `server='paste'` causes the crash, but using the Bottle server it runs OK. The problem seems to happen at the `bottle._handle()` method, where a `UnicodeError` is thrown (`bottle.py` line 844):

```
def _handle(self, environ):
        path = environ['bottle.raw_path'] = environ['PATH_INFO']
        if py3k:
            try:
                environ['PATH_INFO'] = path.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
            except UnicodeError:
                return HTTPError(400, 'Invalid path string. Expected UTF-8')
```

I'm using `Python 3.6.2`, `Bottle v0.12.13` and `Paste 2.0.3` on a Windows 10 machine. What's going on? Is that a problem with Bottle or Paste?

**Note:** I've already solved my problem by refactoring all the code to use integer IDs instead of names. But I still would like to learn more about this.

**Stack trace:**

```
Critical error while processing request: /hello/inglês

Error:

RuntimeError('Request context not initialized.',)
Traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fernando.filho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 1661, in fget
    try: return ls.var
AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'var'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fernando.filho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 954, in wsgi
    out = self._cast(self._handle(environ))
  File "C:\Users\fernando.filho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 907, in _cast
    out = self.error_handler.get(out.status_code, self.default_error_handler)(out)
  File "C:\Users\fernando.filho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 842, in default_error_handler
    return tob(template(ERROR_PAGE_TEMPLATE, e=res))
  File "C:\Users\fernando.filho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 3619, in template
    return TEMPLATES[tplid].render(kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\fernando.filho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 3409, in render
    self.execute(stdout, env)
  File "C:\Users\fernando.filho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 3396, in execute
    eval(self.co, env)
  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\fernando.filho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 1249, in url
    return self.urlparts.geturl()
  File "C:\Users\fernando.filho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 165, in __get__
    key, storage = self.key, getattr(obj, self.attr)
  File "C:\Users\fernando.filho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 1663, in fget
    raise RuntimeError("Request context not initialized.")
RuntimeError: Request context not initialized.
```

Comment: What is `API`? (Can you post a minimal working example, and also the entire exception stack trace?)

Comment: @ron.rothman Pleas, see edit.

Comment: I didn't see a minimal working example in your edits, so I wrote my own. With Python 3.6.2 and Bottle 0.12.13, `GET /languages/Inglês` works perfectly for me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with paste. Can't help you without a minimal example that shows the problem. Good luck!

Comment: FYI, I ran my version with `server='paste'` and it still worked fine.

Comment: I'll provide an example, maybe it's a browser thing, I don't have a clue.

Comment: In case it helps, I'm testing with `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8080/languages/Inglês`

Comment: I tried with Postman app, same error.

Comment: Your curl request is technically not valid as you need to do URL encoding to ensure only ASCII used in URL. The curl program doesn't do it for you. The Paste server is not tolerant of being sent non ASCII characters. Similar issue to https://github.com/Pylons/waitress/issues/127#event-1207624604 and the Python bug reports linked off it.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Confirmed--this fails: `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8080/languages/Ingl%c3%aas`.  Thanks, I had no idea about this.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Can you post this as an answer? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, quoting @GrahamDumpleton:

> The Paste server is not tolerant of being sent non ASCII characters.

Answer (score 0):

this is the bottle's problem!

In order to use paste server u can change this:
"""bottle.py"""

```
environ['PATH_INFO'] = path.encode('latin1').decode('utf8', 'ignore')
```

to:

```
environ['PATH_INFO'] = path.encode('utf8').decode('utf8', 'ignore') #utf-8 or else
```

it's work well.